# Let X be a binomially distributed random variable with mean 2 and variance 4/3. Tabulate the probability distribution of X.

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

I'm practicing for a test that I'm writing tomorrow and one of the past questions was:

**Let X be a binomially distributed random variable with mean 2 and variance 4/3. Tabulate the probability distribution of X.**

For Binomial Distribution, we learnt that the mean (µ) = np, where n is the sample and p is probability of success and the variance σ^2 = np(1 - p).

The only thing I could think of doing is:

2 = np and 4/3 = np(1 - p)

4/3 = 2 (1 - p)

1/3 = p

2 = n(1/3)

n = 6

This is as far as I can get.

Comment: Excellent. Now find $P(X=k)$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ on base of $P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ (or - if there is more to learn for tomorrow and you really understand what's going on - just leave it) ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Great, you have solved the parameters.

Now, you just have to use the formula

$$Pr(X=i) = \begin{cases} \binom{6}{i}\left( \frac13 \right)^i \left( \frac23 \right)^{6-i}& i \in \{ 0, \ldots, 6\}\\ 0 & \text{Otherwise}\end{cases}$$